# Why does PHP 8 return the wrong second Friday of the next Year

Tags: php, datetime

To get the second Friday of next year I used `second Friday of Januar next year`, however, this returns the wrong date. (It's not only the second or Friday, this concerns every date in this fashion)

See following example

```php
$FIRST_FRI_JAN_NEXT_YEAR_TEXT   = 'second friday of january next year';                        
$jan1 = new DateTime($FIRST_FRI_JAN_NEXT_YEAR_TEXT );     // = 22-01-08  // wrong date

$FIRST_FRI_JAN_NEXT_YEAR_NUMBER = 'second friday of 2022-01';
$jan2 = new DateTime($FIRST_FRI_JAN_NEXT_YEAR_NUMBER);    // = 22-01-14  // right date
```

[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc00eb99313bb3d4ab93d80e84ab0d77e9488265)

Is there a reason for that or is this a bug?

Comment: FWIW, I would never rely on this automagic to begin with. The supposed capabilities of that date parsing mechanism are so highly overloaded, it’s almost unpredictable what will or won’t work.

Comment: This is not specific to php 8, the behavior is the same in all php versions since 5.3.0: https://3v4l.org/pEAuS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug. “Second Friday in January next year” is interpreted as “second Friday in January” of this year and “next year” as +1 year. With long expressions it is not always clear in which order they are processed. It is usually better to do this in several steps.

```
$jan2 = date_create('next year')->modify('second friday of january');  //2022-01-14
```